# Excel How to programmatically hide columns while keeping navigation buttons in view at top

Tags: excel, vba, button, hide

I have a wide Excel sheet with some navigation buttons at the top.  When clicking a button, I'd like to either jump to the columns it relates to or else hide the columns to the left of it so the desired data comes into view without scrolling.

However, the columns in which those buttons reside may get collapsed or hidden because those columns also contain data.  So if a user clicks a button to go to a section far to the right, the buttons will go out of view or will get collapsed (hidden) with the columns in which they reside.

What's the best way to do this?
1) Collapse the columns and move all of the buttons above the section being shown?
2) Hyperlink to the appropriate columns and bring the buttons with me?
3) Is there a way to freeze a group or section at the top that will stay even when collapsing columns?
3) Something else I have not thought of?

I'm very knowledgeable in Access and VBA but not as familiar with Excel.  So I'm sure there are a lot of ways this has been handled when you have a wide sheet.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand - suppose I have a button on my sheet in column B and clicking it takes me to column AZ.  Of course, that button isn't visible anymore because it's in column B, which is off to the left of the screen.  How do you intend for that to work?  Or if your question is "how can I make that work", I would suggest having a userform to do the navigation, since that can pop up no matter where you are in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

buttons have the option of `Don't move or size with cells` obviously this does not help with the out of view but will help with the collapsing columns.

To collapse the columns the following should work

```
 Sub hideAtoC
     column_hider "A", "C"
 End Sub

 Sub hideDtoR
     column_hider "D", "R"
 End Sub  

 Sub column_hider(first_column,last_column)
     Sheet1.Columns.Hidden = False
     Worksheets("YOUR WORKSHEET NAME").Range(first_column & ":" & last_column).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
 End
```

Then you just attach your buttons to the appropriate module i.e. `hideAtoC` or `hideDtoR`

Moving the controls gets more complicated based on the number of controls but this will work with some obvious modifications

```
Sub moveWithMe
   With Worksheets("YOUR WORKSHEET NAME")
       .Cells(1,"BA").Select
       .Shapes(1).Left = ActiveCell.Left
   End With
End Sub
```

This is a very simple example all it does is select a cell and then align the button with the cell you case seems more complicated and would probably require an offset for button width Here is a conceptual loop (which will suffer if the cell is in the left most visible column) but you get the idea

```
Dim offset As Long
offset = ActiveCell.Left
For i = 1 To Sheet1.Shapes.Count
     Sheet1.Shapes(i).Left = offset - (Sheet1.Shapes(i).Width / 2)
     offset = offset + Sheet1.Shapes(i).Width + 10
Next i
```

Answer (score 0):

A little late answer, but it may be useful for others.

The userform that we created to hide the columns in the workbook and unhide the hidden columns contains also a button to minimize userform. With to the drop-down list in the userform can be navigated between worksheets, the selected worksheet from the combobox is active and the column management(hide-unhide) of this worksheet is provided.

[image]

We used listbox control on the userform to hide columns :

```
Private Sub ListBox1_Change()                'The columns that selected on listbox are hidden.
Dim gizle As Integer
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
If yukleme = "ok" Then
For gizle = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
  If ListBox1.Selected(gizle) = True Then
       ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Split(ListBox1.List(gizle, 0))(0)).EntireColumn.Hidden = True
   Else
       ActiveSheet.Cells(1, Split(ListBox1.List(gizle, 0))(0)).EntireColumn.Hidden = False
   End If
Next
End If
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

All VBA codes and sample workbook at here :[Excel hide columns](https://eksi30.com/excel-hide-unhide-columns-using-userform/)